# Can I keep two PCs permanently connected on bluetooth for quick file transfers?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

On two Windows 10 PCs, is there a way to maintain a continuous bluetooth connection so files can be freely sent back and forth?

Currently, I have to set the receiving computer to "Receive a File" mode and the sending computer to "Send a File" mode for each transfer.

Also to note, one PC cannot use any WiFi network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workaround: If the non-networked PC has a WiFi card, it still can perform [*ad hoc*, peer-to-peer transfers](https://connectify.me/blog/how-to/set-up-ad-hoc-wifi-windows-10/) without being on the network. The two computers communicate directly, without use of a router. This is has the advantage of likely being faster then Bluetooth, as well.

You can also [direct-wire Ethernet](https://www.dignited.com/34490/how-to-connect-two-windows-10-pcs-without-a-router/) ports on each PC for peer-to-peer transfer, as well.

My experience with Bluetooth is that it may be useful for transferring a file or two, but security updates have made it too cumbersome for steady transfer.